# There are 314 coins in 21 open boxes. In each move you can take 1 coin from each of any two boxes and put them into a third box and...

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

There are 314 coins in 21 open boxes. In each move you can take 1 coin from each of any two boxes and put them into a third box and in the final move you take all the coins from one box. What is the maximum number of coins you can get?

The answer is 314 and I am struggling to prove it is possible to get 314 coins at last for every possible distribution of coins among the 21 boxes.

Comment: Is the number of moves limited?

Comment: No. There is no limit for the number of moves.

Comment: This is not clear. Must I take two coins or can I simply take $1$ if I prefer?  Say we had three coins in three boxes, distributed as $(2,1,0)$.  Then taking one coin from each of the non-empty ones gives you $(1,0,2)$ which is essentially the same.  So is this configuration hopeless?

Comment: It is necessary to take two coins(one coin from each box) at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(10,1,0,0)\to(9,0,2,0)\to(8,2,1,0)\to(7,1,1,2)\to 
(9,0,1,1)\to(11,0,0,0)$$

Comment: How does this sequence help to solve the problem??

Comment: As soon as you have at least four boxes, and at least three coins in box 1, you can fetch any other coin into box 1.

Comment: +1 nice!  And I see you have made an editorial choice between being clear and being cute... and I kinda like your choice, actually.  :)